# Windows doesn't have driver for Generic USB Keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard

For some reason, the Generic USB Keyboard driver was removed, literally, over night, from Windows.

Can someone that has Windows 7 and uses a USB Keyboard without any fancy drivers (i.e. uses Generic Windows USB Keyboard driver) go to

```
Device Manager>Keyboards>USB Keyboard>Properties>Driver>Driver Details
```

and post the name of the driver system files (for example  "C:\Windows\system32\DRIVER\i8042prt.sys")?

Comment: @DaveRook Post the name of the driver system files ... For example "C:\Windows\system32\DRIVER\i8042prt.sys"; this is used for PS/2 Keyboard. Or just take a picture of that window ...

Comment: @DaveRook Yes. Are this files for a generic USB keyboard driver?

Comment: @DaveRook Do you use a USB Keyboard? If yes, did you install any driver or did you just plugged it in and let Windows use it's own generic driver?

Comment: @DaveRook Yes, my Windows is broken. The files for the generic USB Keyboard driver are missing. I haven't tried Windows Repair, but from my experience it just brakes it even more (this is an old Windows 7 installation). All I want is the name of the files for the Generic USB Keyboard driver so I can manually copy them.

Comment: If a system driver disappeared all of sudden that could be a sign of file system corruption and/or hardware failure. Before doing anything, [check your hard disk for errors](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/433-disk-check.html) and then run the [System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html). Report back any error messages.

Comment: @and31415 Sfc didn't find any errors, and I was wrong, the driver files are not missing (bkdhid.sys and kbdclass.sys). It just doesn't load the correct driver for the USB device. In fact, I tested, and there are a bunch of them that don't work any more. Some work, some doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, try a system restore.

If that doesn't help, this is a General Fix for USB Driver Problems

> 1. Unplug all USB devices except mouse and keyboard.
> 2. Click on Start orb, Type Advanced System settings in the search box and Click on View Advanced System Settings to go there.
> 3. Click on Advanced tab, Click on Environment Variables.
> 4. Under the window "System variables" Click on New.
> 5. Type devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices as the variable name and type 1 as the value.
> 6. Click OK 3 times to close the windows.
> 7. Click on Start orb, Type Device Manager in the search box and Click on Device Manager in the list to go there.
> 8. Click on View, then Show hidden devices.
> 9. You will now notice that you have a list of USB devices and that some lines appear to be faded. Uninstall all the faded entries.

More detail and pictures form source: 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/165554-usb-driver-general-fix-problems.html

Comment: You are right, the driver files are not missing, it just doesn't recognize the USB device. After some testing there are actually a bunch of them that don't work any more. I tried your solution, but unfortunately it didn't work. I never really understood how Windows handle USB drivers.

Comment: @Chris, this is more 'common'. Does the keyboard show up in Device manager? It may be while uninstalling the keyboard from device manager, plugging it back in and letting it re-install it

Comment: Yes. It show under "Other devices" as "USB Keyboard" with the correct ids .. USB\VID_04D9&PID_1603. But it doesn't load any driver for it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it doesn't load a driver for it please @Chris?

Comment: When I plug it in it shows that it detected the USB device, and it says that it's looking for a driver. AFter a while it says "No driver found."

Comment: @Chris try http://superuser.com/questions/464300/windows-7-cant-find-driver-deactivates-keyboard-and-mouse and http://superuser.com/questions/619318/windows-7-doesnt-recognize-usb-devices-anymore/619499#619499

Comment: "C:\Windows\inf\usb.inf" was missing. I copied it from another machine and problem is solved. I wonder what removed it in the first place. You can add that link in your answer if you want. Thanks! That was spot on.

Comment: @Chris, glad it is solved for you :)

Comment: As stated @Chris this works. I run a Windows x64 Ultimate, even i copied from an Enterprise edition. Thks!